# How to replace $1 , $2 in string

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, str-replace, replaceall

```
var params = ['tom' , 'harry'];

var string = 'hello $1 and $2  how aa are you $1 and $2';
```

**What i tried**

```
var params = ['tom' , 'harry'];
var string = 'hello $1 ,$2  how aa are you $1 , $2';
var temp;
for(var i = 0; i<params.length ; i++)
{
  temp = string.replace(/[$1]+/g,params[i]);   
}
```

**Firefox console wrong output** : "hello harry ,harry2  how aa are you harry , harry2"

> Final Output : hello tom and harry  how are you tom and harry

Comment: i am trying this in firefox console

Comment: yes i have updated tags :)

Comment: @plutopunch take my code snippet and try it in any browser's console. I tried it in chrome and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One solution:

```
string.replace(/\$1/g, params[0]).replace(/\$2/g,params[1])
```

More explanation:

The reason I put `$1` as `\$1` because `$1, $2,...` have special meaning inside regular expressions. They are considered as special characters. E.g., if you want to search `.` (dot) in your string then you cannot just place `.` in regex because in regex `.` means match any character inside string (including dot too); so, in order to find `.` in your string you've to place(slash `\`) before dot, like `\.` , inside regex, so that regex engine can find exact `.` character.

Comment: @plutopunch mistakenly i placed wrong string. i've edited now and it works fine now. Check updated version.

Comment: @plutopunch then forget the loop i'm editing the answer.

Comment: @plutopunch i wish if they, $1 $2, were not hard-coded :)

Comment: the second solution i gave was also a correct solution . Is there any reason to delete the correct second solution .Also I don't want to write that as other answer

Comment: @plutopunch that solution was more general but due to hard-coded values that doesn't fit there. you can use that as well.

Answer (score 2):

> Replace using SPLIT and JOIN - Don't always need to use **`.replace`**

```
var params = ['tom' , 'harry'];
var string = 'hello $1 ,$2  how aa are you $1 , $2';

for(var i = 0; i<params.length ; i++)
{
  var st = '$' +( i + 1);

  string = string.split(st).join(params[i])
}
```

> OutPut : "hello tom ,harry  how aa are you tom , harry"

Answer (score 1):

**This is An extinction to @muhammad imran solution with for loop**

```
var params = ['tom' , 'dick', 'harry'];

var string = 'hello $1 ,$2  how $3 aa are you $1 , $2  , $3';

var stringToFire = ''

for(var i = 0 ;i<params.length;i++)
{
  var forDollar = i+ 1;
  var forReplacer =   i;
  stringToFire = stringToFire + '.replace(/\\$dollarNumber/g, params[donkey])'.replace('dollarNumber',forDollar).replace('donkey',forReplacer );
}

var ultimateString = 'string'+stringToFire

eval(ultimateString);
```

> Final Output : hello tom and harry how are you tom and harry

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question, if you're really wanting to replace *$1* with *tom*, you would search for *\$1* (notice the escaped *$*) and replace with *tom*.

I have a feeling what you really mean is that you've got some text at the positions where *$1* and *$2* occur. If this is the case, you don't really need to find and replace; you just need to output your variables in those positions.

Comment: javascript firefox console

Comment: and your string actually has dollar signs in it?

Answer (score 0):

```
var params = ['tom', 'harry'];
            var string = "hello $1 en $2";
            string = string.replace("$1", params[0]).replace("$2", params[1]);
```

Comment: This will replace only once @Muhammad imran is having better way :)

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same problem and this is what I end up with:

```js
const params = ['tom' , 'harry'];

const string = 'hello $1 and $2  how aa are you $1 and $2';

const result = params.reduce((acc, val, i) => acc.replace(new RegExp(`\\$${i+1}`, 'g'), val), string);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).